# What is equivalent of LENGTH in GQL

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, gql

Trying to investigate an issue and i need to find all those rows from datastore whose columnX value's length is less than 10.

In regular i could have use the method `LENGTH` but apparently this doesn't exist in datastore. So what can i do?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run a Dataflow job over your database to read all the values of columnN.